# Change Sencha list itemTpl dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, list, css, sencha-touch

How can I change the itemTpl in a sencha list dynamically so that I can set the visibility of a column according to some conditions?

Any Help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a different css class for visible verses invisible.  then use the if syntax to set that class (of the div)

```
class=<tpl if="age > 1">MakeMeVisibleClass</tpl><tpl if="age == 0">MakeMeInVisibleClass</tpl>
```

there is lots of help on templates in the sencha docs.  for example: http://www.sencha.com/learn/template-faq/

Comment: Hi Peter ., thanks for reply . I have done it with another list view since it was urgent for me. I will try ur solution in another instance.